# Too many columns in a single preference db table?

Tags: database, normalization

I have an application that is essentially built out of many smaller applications. Each application has their own individual preferences, but all of them share the same 5 preferences, for example, whether the application is displayed in the nav, whether it is public, whether reports should be generated, etc.

All of these common preferences need to be known by any page in the web app because the navigation is constructed from it. So originally I put all these preferences in a single table. However as the number of applications grow (10 now, eventually around 30), the number of columns will end up being around 150-200 total. Most of these columns are just booleans, but it still worries me having that many columns in one table. On the other hand, if I were to split them apart into separate tables (preferences per app), I'd have to join them all together anyway every time I need to see the preferences, so why not just leave them all together?

In the application I can break the preferences into smaller objects so they are easier to work with, but from a db perspective they are a single entity. Is it better to leave them in one giant table, or break them apart into smaller ones but force many joins every time they are requested?

Comment: so each app has maybe 10 prefs, so the other 150-190 fields are useless to the app? That sort of setup would be better off in separate tables. But it comes down to how many rows there'll be in that prefs table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Which database engine are you using ? normally you will find some recommendations about recommended number of columns per table in your DB engine. Mostly Row size limitations, which should keep you safe.

Other options and suggestions include:

1. Assign a bit per config key in an integer, and use the logical "AND" operation to show only the key you are interested in at a given point in time. Single value read from DB, one quick Logical operation for each read of a config key.
2. Caching the preferences in memory, less round trips to DB servers, Based on frequency of changes , you may also having to clear the cache of each preference when it is updated.

Comment: I can save a lot of columns using the bit per config approach - thanks. This seems the easiest to implement and works best with my apps.

Answer (score 1):

Why not turn the columns into rows and use something like this:

[image: ERD]

This is a typical approach for maintaining lists of settings values.

The `APP_SETTING` table contains the value of the setting.  The `SETTING` table gives you the context of what the setting is.

There are ways of extending this to add information such as which settings apply to which applications and whether or not the possible values for a particular setting are constrained to a specific list.

Answer (score 0):

Well CommonPreferences and ApplicationPreferences would certainly make sense, and perhaps even segregating them in code (two queries instead of a join).

After that a table per application will make more sense.

Another way is going down the route suggested By Joel Brown.

A third would be instead of having individual colums or row per setting, you stuff all the non-common ones in to an xml snippet or serialise from a preferences class.

Which decision you make revolves around how your application does (or could use the data).
If you go down the settings table approach getting application settings as a row will be 'erm painful. Go down the xml snippet route and querying for a setting across applications will be even more painful than several joins.

No way to say what you should compromise on from here. I think I'd go for CommonPreferences first and see where I was at after that.